# How can I make my array searchCategories a key value in my search array

Tags: php

Im doing a filter in a search and have an array of data of:

```
search: Array(2)
    0: "asd"
    1: "sss"
searchCategory: Array(2)
    0: "product_name"
    1: "product_name"
```

I want to store them in array the can be pass using http_build_query()

example ?product_name=asd&product_name=sss

Comment: Loop them and build the string

Comment: that is exactly what im doing but cant seems to get the right logic

Comment: We can't see that you have even tried.

Comment: One simple way is to convert the array to comma-separated string and send them all. `searchCategory.join(',')`. Then convert it back into an array on the server side.

Comment: @Andreas I'm sorry if you think that way perhaps details on my question are lacking.

Comment: @Dan details are fine but all questions should include an attempt or something that proves that you have tried yourself. Usually that is with code that does not give expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop the array and build the string using key to get the $search item.

```
$search = ["asd","sss"];
$category = ["product_name","product_name"];

$str = "?";
// loop category 
foreach($category as $key => $cat){
    $str .= $cat . "="  .$search[$key] . "&"; // add category and search + &
}

$str = rtrim($str, "&"); // remove trailing &
echo $str; //?product_name=asd&product_name=sss
```

Comment: This works, instead of using  http_build_query(). I will just concat my other dataThanks a bunch!

Answer (score -1):

There is a [array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) function for that in PHP.

```
$k = ['k1', 'k2'];
$v = ['v1', 'v2'];

$c = http_build_query(array_combine($k, $v));
```

$c variable will contains: `k1=v1&k2=v2`

And u will need just to add a `?` prefix to it.

Comment: Won't work. an array can't have two keys with the same name

Comment: I know. I think that there is a mistake in example provided: `?product_name=asd&product_name=sss` - there will be only `sss` as  `product_name`.

Comment: @sklwebdev sorry I wasnt clear I'm talking about the return of http_build_query() function because im gonna pass that data in the url to make a request